# Implementing login for users at the frontend

Tags: authentication, frontend, apostrophe-cms

I'm not very used to Apostrophe and currently checking out that CMS.
What I want to do is implementing a user login at the frontend. 
I tried using the apostrophe-user module but users that were created using that module are able to login to the backend and I don't want them to be able to do this.
Is it somehow possible to achieve what I want to do?
Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: I'm also using apostrophe-headless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apostrophe-groups` to create a sub group of users with specific permissions and then check those permissions in various places (like templates) to show or not show certain admin experiences.

https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/permissions.html

You could further customize the login experience of these users by tapping in to the `apostrophe-login`, redirecting them to a special part of the website, etc https://apostrophecms.org/docs/modules/apostrophe-login/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I implemented a redirect module!